# How to achieve such Pivot Table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have the following query to display monthly status of fee for student.

```
SELECT regd, Name_of_Student, Class, Section, Rollno,
If(Month = 'January', Status, 0) AS Jan,
If(Month = 'September', Status, 0) AS Sept  
FROM fee
where Class='XI(Art)' and Rollno='2';
```

The problem with this code is shown here in image:

[image]

What I want to output is like below:

[image]

In real application, I would display all the months.

Please see the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b5b8/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT regd, Name_of_Student, Class, Section, Rollno,
MAX(If(Month = 'January', Status, 0)) AS Jan,
MAX(If(Month = 'September', Status, 0)) AS Sept  
FROM fee
where Class='XI(Art)' and Rollno='2'
GROUP BY regd, Name_of_Student, Class, Section, Rollno;
```

Comment: just go to the fiddle link I provide and paste your code, then you will see the error. And also I don't understand why you are using Name_of_Student, Class, Section, Rollno, regd, all in `group` by.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b5b8/5/0 Works absolutely fine for me. Well, all these columns are duplicate information. With group by you collapse them and with the max() aggregate function you make sure to get the values with highest status.

Comment: I just noticed, that your status field is a varchar. This way you might get wrong results, as max() works then on the alphabet, with P greater than N. You might want to change the column to datatype tinyint with values 0 for not paid and 1 for paid. It's also better performance wise to work with numbers rather than text.